# Completion of App Engine Index Writes (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Is there a way to know / detect if an object (after being put to the datastore) has been written to an index i.e. object would be visible in a relevant query? Maybe something like a hook method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is done asynchronously and you are not able to control this process. Hooks available only for by key gets, not for index queries. Try to build your datastore with parent-child relationships, so you can do ancestor queries, they are always consistent.